# Find certain value and add new value

Tags: mysql, character

I've got a dictionary in a mysql db with international words in it. I want to find these words and insert a new version. Not replace.

**IE** when a user runs a PHP query for the value "currencies", both spellings below comes up in the search results.

**¥en -
Yen**

I had an idea on searching for all rows containing ¥ and replace them with Y and export to a new db/tabel and then import them again to the old DB but there must be a easier solution, right?

`mysql> SELECT * FROM money WHERE name LIKE '%¥%';`

Comment: Welcom to StackOverflow.  Can you provide an example of what the data looks like and what results you are looking for?

Comment: It's a regular mysql db. So it would look like this if you use the example above `(1, '¥en'),
(2, 'USD'),
(3, 'GBP'),
(4, 'Euro'),` and so on.. Number five should then become `(5, 'Yen'),`

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work for your specific example:

```
INSERT INTO money (Field1, Field2, Name)
SELECT Field1, Field2, REPLACE(name, '¥', 'Y') n 
FROM money 
WHERE name LIKE '%¥%';
```

This will insert a new record in your Money table replacing the ¥ with a Y.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

e.g.

```
   INSERT INTO money
      SELECT REPLACE(name,'¥','Y') FROM money WHERE name like '%¥%';
```